# How to connect to an old Rpi Zero?

Tags: ssh, pi-zero-w

I found a Rpi zero that I did not use for 1 year. There is valuable data there, I want to exract it.

Previously I was connecting through the wifi. But meanwhile I changed the router and the Rpi is not connected to the wifi anymore. Whe I am plugging the RPpi int omy mac via USB it is getting powered, but it does not appear in the network devices.
I probably changed the host name of it, so pinging "raspberry.local" would not work too.

How can I connect to the Rpi?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Raspberry Pis have no internal memory.  All data is held on the SD card.

Put the SD card in an SD card reader and you can extract all your valuable data.

Comment: Like I can access the whole file system just plugging it into another computer? Are you sure? Seems like a security backdoor problem then.

Comment: You probably need to use a linux based machine to read the linux partition. Another Pi would work with a usb micro sd reader.

Comment: @Predicate If you can physically access a computer you have total control.  It's no difference to my removing the hard drive from a PC.

Comment: @Predicate this is the reason for whole disk encryption. Since if you can remove the hard drive from a machine, you can mount it and access any data that is on it. This is not specific to pi, thats how any computer would work. (again, assuming there is no disk encryption)